# Preencher label automaticamente quando o stage abrir - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Preciso que uma `label` receba um texto automaticamente assim que o `stage` for iniciado, sem precisar clicar em um botão.
Como são diferentes textos salvos em um banco de dados, preciso que eles sejam carregados na label quando o `stage` iniciar.

Existe algum método pra isso?

Está é a classe controller da aplicação:

```
public class DesafioController {
    @FXML Button btnCancelar = new Button();
    @FXML TextArea AreaSolucao = new TextArea();
    @FXML Label labelDesafio = new Label();
    @FXML AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();

    @FXML
    void clickRecomecar() {
        //Reinicia o desafio do zero, apagando o que já foi escrito.
        AreaSolucao.setText("TESTE RECOMEÇAR");
    }

    @FXML
    void clickCancelar() {
        //Fecha o desafio voltando para o jogo.
        Stage atual = (Stage) btnCancelar.getScene().getWindow();
        atual.close();
    }

    @FXML
    void clickEnviar() {
        //Aqui será enviado a solução do desafio para o banco de dados.(INSERT)
    }
}
```

Janela da aplicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Existe, porém edite sua pergunta e inclua o código do que tem até o momento.

Comment: @Renan, inclui o código e um print da janela da aplicação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode sobrescrever o comportamento do método [`initialize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html#initialize-java.net.URL-java.util.ResourceBundle-), que resumidamente é o método chamado quando todos os controles anotados por `@FXML` forem injetados. Para isso, sua classe de controle deve implementar [`Initializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html):

```
public class DesafioController implements Initializable {

   private @FXML Label label;

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, Resources res)
      label.setText("Texto Inicial.");
   }
}
```

Comment: Deu certo!! Obrigado Renan!